# Display fading animation for image texture planes in 3D viewport?

Tags: animation

This has been questioned before but was answered unsatisfactorily.
Is there a way to animate the opacity of image texture planes in the blender render view port?

[image: Alpha Factor only updates on the slider]

I need the image to have a very simple, very common, non-CPU intensive, 
Fade-in fade-out Effect.
The problem is that the Alpha Factor of the texture only updates on the panel slider and not in the actual animation key-framing doesn't seem to work on this. Is there a simple tick box somewhere that solves this simple problem?

Comment: Do you want to make the texture disappear, or the plane with that material?

Comment: i want to give it a fade-in fade-out animation 
[ plane image with alpha pixels ]

Comment: its definitely working in the slider, but why not when being played?

Comment: you haven't answered my question

Comment: I'm using vers 2.77a and definitely cannot fade out an alpha layered image plane using keyframes in the 3D window.  If rendering in OpenGL, this problem can be circumvented by mixing two videos in the VSE, the fading one and others.  The VSE uses Blender-render internal, but it is hugely faster in the VSE.  Hope this helps...